# Easy VBA Macro to list all worksheets generates error: Type Mismatch

Tags: excel, for-loop, excel-2007, vba

I'm making a ExcelComparer but I bump into a probably obvious error, I clearly missed something.

I run a vba macro in Excel 2007

The exact error I get is "Run-time Error 13: Type Mismatch"
This happens when the loop tries to fetch the second worksheet.name .
So, the first sheetname is returned fine

Below you find the macro

Thanks in advance,
L

```
Sub compare()

Dim strWorkbook1, strWorkbook2 As String
Dim Workbook1, Workbook2 As Workbook
strWorkbook1 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C5") & Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D5")
strWorkbook2 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C6") & Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D6")

Set xlapp = CreateObject("Excel.application")
Set Workbook1 = xlapp.Workbooks.Open(strWorkbook1)
xlapp.Visible = False

Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In Workbook1.Sheets
  'ws.Select
  If Not ws.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden Then
      MsgBox (ws.Name)
  End If
Next ws
xlapp.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: `Dim strWorkbook1, strWorkbook2 As String` is the same as `Dim strWorkbook1 As Variant, strWorkbook2 As String`, is that what you meant?

Comment: Thx JP, I believe `Dim strWorkbook1, strWorkbook2 As String` is right as they are both strings

Comment: If they are both strings, then it should be `Dim strWorkbook1 As String, strWorkbook2 As String`. Also, if this code is in Excel then why are you using CreateObject? Just use `Set xlapp = Excel.Application`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use this for your For loop:

```
For Each ws In Workbook1.Worksheets
```

From MSDN the difference between the Sheets and Worksheets properties are:

> This property does not return macro sheets, charts, or dialog sheets.
>   Use the Sheets property to return those sheets as well as worksheets.
>   You can also use the specialized properties Excel4MacroSheets and
>   Excel4IntlMacroSheets to return macro sheets and the Charts property
>   to return charts.

Comment: God... sometimes you look over these little (but in a way stupid) things! Thanks a lot, that was the problem! L

Answer (score 1):

*[Edited my original response as I had tested with different variables rendering my comment incorrect]*

In addition the back end of your code will fail as you can't set the Excel Application to close with this line `xlapp.Close`

You should

1. close the automated workbook (`Workbook1.Close False`)
2. quit the automated application (`xlapp.Quit`)
3. Ensure the automated application is destroyed (`Set xlapp = Nothing`)a

The working part of your code should look like this

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In Workbook1.WorkSheets
  If Not ws.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden Then MsgBox (ws.Name)
Next ws
Workbook1.Close False
xlapp.Quit
Set xlapp = Nothing
End Sub
```